# Display FSRM storage quota details on ASP.NET site

Tags: windows-server-2008, asp.net, disk-space-utilization

I am running FSRM on SBS 2008 to apply storage quotas to user folders. Is it then possible to display these user specific quotas and usage when the user logs onto an intranet website that is using ASP.NET?

i.e. User1 logs onto the intranet to see a message that says he has a quota limit of 5Gb on a specific folder and he is using 4GB of it.

Thanks,

Michael